# Align Title Horizontally Using Material-Ui and CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui, jss

I need to align the title `Hello John Joseph Jones` horizontally on the top BUT inside the black box.
The problem that it consumes the space vertically.
I don't if my code is good. Feel free to revise if there is a better way to do this.

[image]

Codesandbox is here [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-forked-lqdii?file=/SampleCard.js)

```
  <Box m={3}>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="column"
        className={classes.container}
        spacing={2}
      >
        {/* <h1>Hello John Joseph Jones</h1> */}
        <Grid item xs={6} className={classes.pictureSection}>
          <div className={classes.imageSection}>
            <img
              src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"
              className={classes.img}
              alt="no pic"
            />{" "}
            <p className={classes.precinctNo}>PR&nbsp; 4838390</p>
            <p className={classes.controlNo}>555555</p>
          </div>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={6} className={classes.nameAddressSection}>
          <Box className={classes.fontText}>John Joseph Jones</Box>

          <Box mt={1} className={classes.fontText}>
            26 South Hawthorne Drive Tonawanda, NY 14150
          </Box>

          <Box mt={1}>
            <QRCode size={80} value={"4234432"} />
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
```

Comment: Do you want your title above the image? Sorry, I don't quite get what you want to achieve

Comment: @yourbraineatsyou. yes, above. center of screen. between the two columns. But dont change the width and height of the black box

Comment: so your title is "inside" of the image?

Comment: @yourbraineatsyou. updated my image above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your Code:

Inserted the new h1 tag, styled it, and changed the Grid direction from `column` to `row`.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import QRCode from "react-qr-code";
import { red } from "@material-ui/core/colors";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  button: {
    color: "white"
  },
  hideButton: {
    visibility: "hidden"
  },
  imageSection: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: "100%"
  },
  img: {
    height: "4cm",
    width: "4cm",
  },
  h1: { // new
    fontSize: "0.70rem",
    width: "100%",
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: "0.1rem"
  },
  precinctNo: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    margin: "0",
    fontSize: "0.70rem",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    color: "#000"
  },
  controlNo: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    margin: "0",
    fontSize: "0.70rem",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    color: "#000"
  },
  boxBorder: {
    border: "3px solid black"
  },
  container: {
    width: "8.5cm",
    height: "5.5cm",
    borderRadius: "3px",
    border: "3px solid #000000",
    color: "#00000"
  },
  pictureSection: {
    display: "flex",
    flexBasis: "100%"
  },
  nameAddressSection: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    textAlign: "center",
    flexBasis: "100%",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  alignItems: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  fontText: {
    color: "#000000",
    fontSize: "0.70rem",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textTransform: "uppercase"
  }
}));

const SampleCard = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Box m={3}>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="row" // new
        className={classes.container}
        spacing={2}
      >
        <h1 className={classes.h1}>Hello John Joseph Jones</h1> // new
        <Grid item xs={6} className={classes.pictureSection}>
          <div className={classes.imageSection}>
            <img
              src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"
              className={classes.img}
              alt="no pic"
            />{" "}
            <p className={classes.precinctNo}>PR&nbsp; 4838390</p>
            <p className={classes.controlNo}>555555</p>
          </div>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={6} className={classes.nameAddressSection}>
          <Box className={classes.fontText}>John Joseph Jones</Box>

          <Box mt={1} className={classes.fontText}>
            26 South Hawthorne Drive Tonawanda, NY 14150
          </Box>

          <Box mt={1}>
            <QRCode size={80} value={"4234432"} />
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default SampleCard;
```

Watch out for the comments in your return statement. (I don't know if they will break your application)

Comment: Upvoted you. pls also do to me. Thank you for your work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by changing the structure a little

Add a root class to hold the main box

```
root: {
    width: "8.5cm",
    height: "5.5cm",
    border: "3px solid #000000",
    borderRadius: "3px",
    boxSizing: "border-box"
  },
```

Remove the border from the container class

```
  container: {
    color: "#00000",
    height: "100%"
  },
```

Apply it to the parent element

```
<Box className={classes.root} m={3}>
```

Add the centered text

```
<Box mb={1} className={classes.fontText} align="center">
        Hello John Joseph Jones
</Box>
```

Take a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-forked-dvoun?file=/SampleCard.js:197-252

In the example above I add some padding to the parent element, as now it holds the border, there may be other ways of doing that to keep the style

To keep the fixed size you will need to play around with the elements

Comment: Pls don't change the width and height of the black box

Comment: Hello John Joseph Jones should be there. Also the name should still be there

Comment: Updated to keep the size but as you can see some changes are needed

Comment: Thank you!!! I upvoted you. pls also do to me